# Pushing maven property in Spring ApplicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven

I want to push project.version from maven to appicationContext.xml as follows,

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/${project.version}/**" location="/static/"/>
```

In pom.xml, I have configured maven filter as follows

```
<resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                  <include>**/applicationContext.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>

</resources>
```

Filter work correctly but applicationContext.xml moved to class folder in target directory. I want it to be in WEB-INF directory. Want have dynamic applicationContext.xml for cache busting for static resources

Configuration: Using Spring 3.2.xxx

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are filtering a web resource as a normal resource, and this resources are copied to classpath.

To properly filter a web resource as you want, drop your `<resources>` section and try this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This way it will work as you want.

Comment: Hi @malaguna, its not working out for me, filtering not applied to appilcationContext.xml. Is there any other configuration, I am missing out. is there other way to get project.version configured in maven to applicationContext.xml

Comment: Let me check some details. Did you place this pluging under `<build>`->`<plugins>` maven section? Is the path to `applicationContext` correct?

Comment: yes i placed it under buid->plugins maven section. Path was also correct. But some how its not working for me. so tried java way of configuring it